# Push notification on Android TV

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-tv, android-push-notification

I am working on an Android TV app, where in which I have a use-case to trigger some views once you get a push notification. Before starting on it I would like to know if Android TV supports push notification as it does in phones and tablets?

I don't want to display the notification to the user, I would be considering it as a *silent* one and I would like to parse the payload contents and display a new view on the TV once a notification arrives. Will the normal notification handling used for phones/ tablets work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Android TV supports FCM. Libraries and implementation are the same.

However, it does not work the same as for phones as tablets, since the TV does not have a system bar. On the cases where the system will automatically display the notification on the system bar, it does nothing.

In your particular case, it will work fine, since you want to always get the FCM message and then process it on the background.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My intention is to get the payload data and do some operations, no need to display. One more question do we need to get user permission?

Comment: it works exactly as standard FCM, same permissions. I don't recall get user being needed.

Comment: I tried with Android TV emulator and it works I was able to receive pushes from FCM, accepting the answer.

Comment: I want to receive a payload while app in background and show some custom view as an overlay on top of other apps too. How can i do this? Please help